# Teleporting rooms glitch

Tags: gml

Whenever i go to a particular area it always teleports back to the center hallway.* Example:(https://www.dropbox.com/s/mye0k8n9ysua6cb/Video%203-29-2017%206-24-13%20PM.avi?dl=0)

*I've tried deleting and changing a bunch of objects and I'm pretty sure it's related to the player*

The code is quite interesting so I'll just link the project(https://www.dropbox.com/s/bmjj7fyxc5qasbg/Undertale%202%20above%20the%20underground.project.gmx?dl=0)

I am using game maker studio 1.4

Comment: Right... and what is your question? Please break down your problem to a minimal example which does fail. This is not a debug-my-whole-codebase workshop. Also include the relevant code directly so that it remains a sensible question without the links - without the dropbox links your question becomes in the current form completely worthless

Comment: i don't know what object it comes from so if i tried to give relavent code it would bee the exact same thing

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explained your problem very well, however, if you used the **Previous room** event that might be the problem because it backs the previous room that listed not the one used.
and you can create an invisible object to teleport between rooms, for example;

1. create an object like **level1_2** then create a sprite & collision box for it.
2. place it in the hallway then use `goto_room(room_level2);` with the collision event.
3. duplicate the object **level1_2** and rename it to **Level2_1**
4. change the code to `goto_room(room_level1);`

this should cause no problem because it is the by far the most reliable time-consuming way.